# VisualStudio 19 constantly deletes Nuget Packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, auto-delete

I have a strange issue:

While i'm coding, my Visual Studio randomly -out of nowhere- says it cannot find the previously installed Nuget Packages. Then it marks half of my code with errors as the packets for the usings are missings.

I then have to download them again and the issue is instantly fixed. These package deletions happen completely out of the blue and since a week over and over again. I cannot track down the issue why it deletes these packages in the first place (?) (or is unable (?) to find downloaded Packages).

Is there a known fix to this?

Comment: How did you encounter this issue? Did  you encounter this problem every time you download a project from a collaboration platform such as TFS? Not sure how this bahavior happens. And if you face this issue next time, please store your nuget packages-->Right -click on the solution-->`Restore Nuget Packages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These package deletions happen completely out of the blue and since a
>   week over and over again. I cannot track down the issue why it deletes
>   these packages in the first place

I wonder if you download the project from any code hosting platforms like TFS before you encouter this issue. And from your description, the nuget references are missing which is not a normal behavior. Also, I want to know exactly what you did to cause this issue.

To troubleshoot your issue, you can try these steps:

**1)** close the VS Instance, delete `NuGet.Config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(User Name)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`, restart VS and then restore nuget packages.

**2)** Besides, every time you encouter this issue, Right-click on the Solution-->`Restore Nuget Packages` and this will restore any nuget missing nuget packages.

**In addition**,  please make sure these two options are checked by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->General-->`Nuget Restore`. And the missing packages will be restored automatically when you execute **Build**.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: I could track this down, it deletes the packages everytime i build the solution...extremely strange. I made a short 30secs Video showing what happens: https://youtu.be/UKlx9KXO0EY

Comment: Based on your video, this is quite a strange behavior and l wonder if there is an error on your environment or a specific nuget package which can do some configuration such as delete some packages. 1) try to [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in vs installer  2) disable any third party extensions or use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your VS and then test your project to check whether it is caused by some extensions.

Comment: 3) create a new empty project and then install the nuget packaes one by one and then build to test whether there is a nuget package which has this behavior to manage other nuget packages such as delete nuget packages . Based on this, when you has finishing installing all the nuget packages and it does not show this behavior, I think there is something with your project. If so,check your codes to see whether it is caused by some specifc codes. Or delete .vs hidden folder under the path of the solution.